# Change modifier of variable to final

Tags: android, modifier

I have a function to which i am passing a `View` as parameter. Now when i use `statusView` in the function  `onAnimationEnd` , the compiler gives a message to change the modifier of `statusView` to `final` . So i dont understand why this is necessary?

```
private void showProgress(Context c, View statusView) {


            statusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            statusView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                    .alpha(show ? 1 : 0)
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            statusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE
                                    : View.GONE);
                        }
                    });

}
```

Comment: can u post complete code? or declare variable as class variab;e

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable statusView is outside of the object created by `AnimatorListenerAdapter`, it must be known at compile time and, thus, be declared final. However, you can just resolve it by declaring it final in the parameter list (in line 1).